# Not able to loop over XML tags in groovy properly

Tags: database, groovy, soapui

I was able to send a webrequest by soapUI which gives me  data in XML format as response .I want to insert the value of xml tag in database tables.

This is what I have tried :

```
def response = context.expand('${Request1#Response}')


def xml =  new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
```

Content of 'response' variable :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:sawsoap="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v7">
<soap:Body>
<sawsoap:executeXMLQueryResult>
         <sawsoap:return xsi:type="sawsoap:QueryResults">
<sawsoap:rowset xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">

<Row>
<Column0>John</Column0>

</Row>

<Row>

    <Column0>Max</Column0>
</Row>
</rowset>]]></sawsoap:rowset>
<sawsoap:queryID xsi:type="xsd:string">RSXS4_1</sawsoap:queryID>
<sawsoap:finished xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sawsoap:finished>
</sawsoap:return>
 </sawsoap:executeXMLQueryResult>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Content of 'xml' :

```
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
<Row>
<Column0>John </Column0>
</Row>
<Row>
<Column0>Max </Column0>
</Row>
</rowset>RSXS4_1true
```

Please note 'RSXS4_1true' is getting appended in 'xml' because of which I am not able to use

```
xml.Row.each{ Row-> log.info "${Row.Column0.text()}"  }
```

to loop through the xml tags .

To be more precise I want to fetch 'John' and 'Max' and insert them in some table.
Any help is most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data is in a CDATA block, it is treated as a String (and then needs to be re-parsed as it is XML)

```
// Parse the xml
def xml =  new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)

// Get the cdata text
def cdata = xml.Body.executeXMLQueryResult.return.rowset.text()

// Re-parse it
def innerXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(cdata)

// Then iterate the rows
innerXml.Row.each { row ->
    println row.Column0.text()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim !! It worked . I am new to groovy .Could you please let me know the meaning of Cdata

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean is an XML thing

Comment: Hi Tim .. I am trying to dump huge data (the reponse which I am getting) to database table . So inserting each record one by one is taking lot of time .Is there a way to improve the performance wherein I can use something else to insert the data more efficiently ?

Comment: You can use `withBatch` in [groovy sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch-groovy.lang.Closure-)

Comment: Thanks Tim . I have explored withBatch and tried using it in my code . Could you please check my original question wherein I have mentioned the error I am facing .

Comment: You haven't posted the error :-(  Also, this feels like another separate question? ;-)

Comment: Hi Tim ,I have posted a different question for the error .Please find the link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364341/how-to-use-addbatch-withbatch-properly-for-bulk-inserting-xml-tag-value-to-datab

Comment: One more request . Could you please upvote my question as 'useful' ? since I am a beginner and it will help me ask more questions :)