# How to use AddBatch/withBatch properly for bulk inserting xml tag value to database table

Tags: xml, database, oracle, groovy, soapui

'innerXml' is a xml file with huge number of xml tags . I am trying fetch the tag values and dump them into database table .
I have tried below code and it is working fine .

```
innerXml.Row.each { Row ->

sql.execute("INSERT INTO tab1(col1,col2) VALUES (${Row.Column0.text()},${Row.Column1.text()} )")
```

But as there is huge number of xml tags its causing performance issue to insert record one by one . As the experts suggested I tried using withBatch to improve performance.Please find the below code which I tried with withBatch :

```
sql.withBatch(386, """  insert into tab1(col1,col2) values (?, ?) """) { ps ->   innerXml.Row.each { Row ->ps.addBatch(${Row.Column0.text()} ,${Row.Column1.text()})  }}
```

But I am getting below error :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script41.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script41$_run_closure2_closure3_closure4) values: [Script41$_run_closure2_closure3_closure4@23724e8d] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure) error at line: 38
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
// 386 is an odd batch size?
sql.withBatch(386, 'insert into tab1(col1,col2) values (?, ?)') { ps ->
    innerXml.Row.each { row ->
        ps.addBatch(row.Column0.text(), row.Column1.text())
    }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome Tim !! It worked ! But when I did this : sql.withBatch(386, """insert into tab1(col1,col2) values (?, ?)""") { ps ->
    innerXml.Row.each { row ->
        ps.addBatch(100,1111)  ..it worked .Could you please clarify the reason 
    }
}

Comment: I am not sure why I am not able to upvote your answer :(

Comment: @joe the issue was you don't need to wrap your values in `${...}` like `${Row.Column0.text()}` when you're not in a templated string

Comment: Okay .Got it ! Do I need to give 386 ?386 is the number of rows here  . I have checked that the table gets populated even if I dont mention 386 .

Comment: 386 is the size of the batch, so every time you reach 386 items, the batch will be processed, and a new batch created.  If you leave it out, it reverts to the default (which is 0), so ALL items will get put in a single batch.  This is fine for your case (as you have a small number of elements), but if you had millions, you'd want to set a batch size to reduce memory usage

Comment: Okay Got it . Thank You !!

Comment: No worries!  Glad to help!  Have fun :-D